# How to modify core applications

Tags: android, android-source

I want to modify the core applications like Settings.apk and install on my own android phone.I don't want to publish it on market. I have following doubts

1. Where can I get source code for core applications?
2. What are the things I need  to do this?
3. Please tell me steps to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the source code here:  https://android.googlesource.com

Keep in mind that the packages there might not be the ones on your phone as each vendor can provide a replacement of their own, the Camera for instance is almost never the google app.

You will also have to decide which version you want since each OS version has revisions that take advantage of newer API's etc.

As far as what you need pretty much the same thing you need to build android apps, eclipse, the sdk, tools etc. http://developer.android.com

You will of course have to remove the application from your phone before installing the new one since your signing certificate will not match.  There can be difficulties when you swap out your own version so be sure to save the original.

Comment: Thankyou for the information.Core apps are in System\app which we can't access.So how can i uninstall and Intsall apps in System\app

Comment: You have to root your phone, google on how to do that, different phones require different measures.